# Jquery slider opens up a HTML page based on location

Tags: jquery, slider

So I have this Jquery slider.

https://jqueryui.com/slider/#custom-handle

I'd like to start te slider at value 50 in the middle.

when it gets 49 or les I'd like to open a page  http://www.nu.nl
if it gets 51 or more I'd like to open op a page http://www.google.nl

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Custom handle</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #custom-handle {
    width: 3em;
    height: 1.6em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -.8em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.6em;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var handle = $( "#custom-handle" );
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
      value: 50, 
      create: function() {
        handle.text( $( this ).slider( "value" ));
      },
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        handle.text( ui.value );
        let value = $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "value")
        if(value < 50 ){
            // use this to redirect
            //window.location.href = "http://www.nu.nl"
            
            console.log(value + " is-less then 50")
         }else if (value > 50 ) {
            // use this to redirect
            //window.location.href = "http://www.google.nl"
            
            console.log(value + " is-gearter then 50")
         }
        
      }
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="slider">
  <div id="custom-handle" class="ui-slider-handle"></div>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh man! that works out so perfectly!!! you are the man! thank you 1000x.